# Should I call my UUID primary key column ID or not?

Tags: postgresql, naming-convention, uuid

I'm working on a database design that extensively uses `UUID`s for `PRIMARY KEY`s. However, this confronts me with a very consequential choice. How do I name these columns? I would call them `uuid`, except that, `UUID` being an identifier, I then have to quote the field name everywhere:

```
CREATE TABLE thingie (
  "uuid" UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT public.gen_random.uuid(),
  foo VARCHAR,
  bar VARCHAR,
);
```

A straight-forward alternative seems to be to instead call these columns `id`:

```
CREATE TABLE thingie (
  id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT public.gen_random.uuid(),
  foo VARCHAR,
  bar VARCHAR,
);
```

That way, I don't have the column name, and semantically I can argue that a UUID is indeed a sort of ID; in a Venn diagram, the UUID circle would be placed wholly in the ID circle.

*However*, I (and I am sure many others with) have grown so accustomed to associating `id` with an auto-incrementing `INTEGER` column that I'm afraid to break some sort of unspoken rule by calling these IDs `id`s.

If you would brighten up my confusion with some solid bike-shedding, I would be much obliged. Indeed my question is: **How would *you* call your `UUID`-typed surrogate keys and why?**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You shouldn't ascribe meaning to your surrogate keys beyond the fact that they are a unique identifier for each row, as such it doesn't matter what format it takes from the point of view of your schema design. All you should care about at that point is that it is a value that identifies something, so I stick with calling them `ID`⁰.

In fact what you have with a UUID, unless you have had a brain-fart and stored them as strings¹, *is* effectively a large integer. You can't do arithmetic on it³ but the engine doesn't see it as any different to a bigger `BIGINT` being used as a key.

Another general thing is that I try to avoid any name (for a column, table, function, procedure, ...) that could be a keyword so need escaping. This is a point against calling them `uuid` if the main point for calling them `id` is not enough. Of course this can't be perfect, I would avoid `uuid` as I know it is a type name in Postgres but devs who have only ever use SQL Server up to this point might not know that as it isn't a reserved word (or even a type name) there, and I might well use words that are not portable elsewhere similarly.

If you effectively store multiple surrogate keys due to integrating with another systems that use something else, your internal identifier, is `id`. The others are real data with meaning so far as your system is concerned, not actually surrogate keys, and should be named in a way that describes their content or use. Real world examples include ISBN, StaffReferenceNumber/SRN, IRN, PPN, …, but you might also have something less general like SalesForceId or JoesPartStoreId. Even if you don't define a surrogate key in these circumstances⁴, keep the meaningful names instead of just `id` so it is obvious that your rules probably don't control their generation and use.

<sup>[0] or id or Id, keeping consistent with the casing rules you follow elsewhere just in case your stuff ends up being interpreted in a case sensitive way later.</sup>

<sup>[1] I still maintain a legacy system that made this mistake two decades ago, a little before my time. It all *works* but of course there are storage size and performance “considerations”, and interesting bugs² lead to invalid UUID values such as empty-string turning up.</sup>

<sup>[2] I'm also counting past bad colleagues, including that young David Spillett who messed up a few such times many years ago, as bugs in the business!</sup>

<sup>[3] Well, you *could* if you tried hard enough, but not with any built-in functions.</sup>

<sup>[4] I would always have a surrogate key in these cases anyway. This means only your bugs can cause issues like duplicate keys or the need for expensive primary key value changes that affect many foreign keys, instead of being beholden to dealing with other systems' bugs too.</sup>

Comment: I cannot find what [2] points to in the text...

Comment: @htmlcoderexe - it is actually in the previous footnote. I must get better at thinking and writing in a less nested manner!

Comment: @DavidSpillett As a notorious footnote nester myself, I request that you please do not stop this most sacred of bad habits.

Answer (score 21):

"uuid" is **not** an [SQL key word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html). Neither in standard SQL, nor in **PostgreSQL**. It's  the name of the [data type `uuid`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-uuid.html) - which, technically, does not stand against using "uuid" as identifier (even without double-quotes).

"id" is a *non-reserved* key word in standard SQL since SQL:2011. But non-reserved key words can be used as identifier freely.

So you *can* use either. Doesn't mean you *should*. My personal opinion is that "id" (as well as "uuid") are not sufficiently descriptive names. I consider the wide-spread use of "id" to be an anti-pattern. Any non-trivial query in a relational database joins multiple tables. Then you end up with multiple columns, all named "id", and you have to table-qualify or deal out aliases. While you still *can* (or even should) do that, it's better if don't have to.

On top of that, I avoid basic type names as identifiers. Unnecessary confusion. Confusing error messages, problems with searching, typo traps, etc.

Use descriptive, legal, lower-case, unquoted identifiers, as short as possible, as long as necessary.
Related:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20880247/939860)

My preferred naming pattern is to use "foo_id" as name for a surrogate primary key column of a table named "foo". It's the *ID* of my *foo* entity, no matter its data type. And I use the same name for any foreign key column referencing it (with the same content). The label on the column represents what's in it, queries are clear. Quick ad-hoc queries can join tables with `USING (foo_id)`.

I do **not** normally include the data type in the column name. (Except when that's common practice for the term.) That's just too noisy. I don't call my price column <strike>"price_numeric"</strike>, nor my name column <strike>"surname_text"</strike>. What if you have to change the data type of your `foo_id` column from `integer` to `bigint`? You wouldn't want to change the column name and propagate that change to all written code ...

Accordingly, I use "foo_id", not <strike>"uuid"</strike> or <strike>"id_uuid"</strike>. The regular user only needs to know that "foo_id" is a unique (PK) ID column of the table "foo". The data type is an implementation detail interesting for special / advanced purposes.

Comment: I always qualify all my column names in non-trivial queries anyway, so that is not a very strong argument against a plain `id` for me. Your other reason in favor of `<table>_id` jives better with me. Do you do the table name prefix just for the surrogate key column (which I've considered too with somewhat ), or also for other columns (which I myself, as a Mindless Qualifier Of All Columns, consider an anti-pattern)?

Comment: @BigSmoke: I prefix only the PK, and only when the name would otherwise be a commonplace like "id". I consider it too noisy to prefix all column names, seems we have an accord there.